# How users to change stimul design in application?

Tags: wpf, stimulsoft

I created a report with stimul and show it in my application.

```
StiReport report = new StiReport();
report.Load(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Report.mrt");
report.RegData("Table", lststudent);
report.Compile();
report.Show();
```

I want that users change report design  without install stimul in user's system.

It is possible that users change report design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stimulsoft has a built-in functionality to let end user changes the design of the reports distributed with your application.
Of course, on the end user machine, you need to install some distributable assemblies listed in the User Manual help file, but you don't need to install the full report designer on the end user machine (and you are not legally allowed to install it) .

The only thing you need to do in code is to call the

```
report.Design();
```

instead of `report.Show();`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I add necessary dll in Application.

Answer (score 1):

You even don't need to install assemblies.
It's enough to put all necessary assemblies to the bin folder of your project.